# How to solve this vector differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve this differential equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\mathbf{x}(t)}{dt} = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}(t))
\end{equation}
where $x$ is an $n$-dimensional vector, and $\mathbf{f}$ is a non-linear vector-valued function (also of dimension $n$).

Can I write:
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{1}{\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})} {d\mathbf{x}} = \int dt \quad ?
\end{equation}

But I am not good at vector calculus and I don't know what is the exact meaning of such an integral.  Any elaboration of this would be helpful.  Thanks!

======== edit ========

Modifying the above idea:
$$ d\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}) dt $$

Maybe I can create an $n \times n$ diagonal matrix $\Gamma$ such that:
$$ \Gamma \mathbf{f} = \mathbf{1}$$
In other words,
$$ \Gamma = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1/{\mathbf{f}_1} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1/\mathbf{f}_i \end{array} \right] $$

Then:
\begin{eqnarray}
\Gamma d\mathbf{x} &=& \mathbf{1} dt \\
\int \Gamma d\mathbf{x} = \int \mathbf{1} dt &=& \mathbf{1} t \\
\int \frac{1}{\mathbf{f}_i} d\mathbf{x}_i &=& t \quad \quad (i = 1,..,n)
\end{eqnarray}

Is that viable?

Comment: I think not, because your first equation implies that $f$ is vector valued, so is hard to interpret $1/f$.

Comment: Any other clue how to solve it? :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write what you have...

If $f$ is linear, then you can easily solve the system using eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

If $f$ is non-linear, the best you can do is obtain local solutions around the critical points of the system. i.e. all $x_0$ such that $f( x_0) = 0$. If this is the case, and $f$ is nice enough, we have that
$$ f(x) \approx \underbrace{f(x_0)}_{= 0} + \text{Jacobian}_F(x_0) (x- x_0) + \ldots $$
Therefore you can easily find a local solution around $x_0$ by checking
$$ \dot z = J z $$
with $J$ begin the Jacobian at $x_0$

Edit. Still... your logic doesn't make sense. what is $dx$ here ? In coordinate representation, you have
$$ \dot x = f(x) \iff \frac{d x_i }{dt} =f_i(x_1,\ldots , x_n ) \quad \forall i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n\}$$
Thus dividing each component by $f_i$ gives
$$  \frac{1}{f_i(x_1, \ldots , x_n )} \frac{d x_i }{dt} =1 \quad \forall i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n\} $$
which isn't separable, so we're no where closer to solving the problem.

Comment: Nice.... but can you see if my new solution (edited above) is correct?

Comment: I think you're confused about what $\dot x = f(x)$ means.... the integration doesn't make sense since you haven't isolated the dependent variables.